# Deleting pfd files after sending as mail attachments

Tags: batch-processing, smtpclient

I know its kind of repeated question but m getting an error message as 'File cannot be accessed as it is being used by other process'. When I run my exe through a batch process.
On running the exe directly in the remote server, I donot get any such error but batch process causes this to happen. The batch process goes into an infinite loop and never ends. even though the exe functions properly. Reports are created and I recieve them as mail attachment.

M using smtpclient to send mails. I ahve also used MailMessage.Attachments.Dispose() and MailMessage.Dispose() to kill the attachment objects.

Comment: It might be better to add some details: platform (Windows?), the kind of batch processing (.bat?), maybe other observed feats: not doubly run, directory structure.

Comment: platform - Windows XP. I have no idea of batch process as thts been taken care by an entire different group of people. Basically, when I am just creating the records and sending as mail attachments, no error occurs. job is successful. but when i hv to delete reports after sending mails, the job kind of goes into an infinite loop. m not even sure if its the vb.net code problem or something related to batch process!

Comment: Sorry I have no idea. Search a tool to inspect which process holds those file handles. There is the **sysinternals** tool suite, which I haven't used the last years; maybe it has something.

Answer (score 0):

I got the correct way. 
I was disposing the mailmessage object first and then the attachment object.
Just had to reverse the order and it worked perfectly!
Thanks!